# What exactly does this sequence correspond to ? (Graph Theory)

Tags: graph-theory

https://oeis.org/A117747

I read the title of course, but I don't understand : the number of configurations of cycles of a given length k should simply be 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the "EXAMPLE" in the OEIS entry.  This should make it clear that we are doing the following.

Draw a cycle of three vertices with undirected edges between them.  Now change some, or all, or none, of the edges to directed arrows.  (That's what "graphs containing directed and undirected links" means in the title.)  You will find that there are $7$ different (non-isomorphic) ways to do this.

For example, if one edge remains undirected and the other two become arrows, there are three options: the two arrows go towards the undirected edge, or away from it, or one of each.

The sequence gives the number of options for a similar process starting with $n$ vertices, $n\ge3$.